Logarithmic approximation of the growth rate of a variable that grows at a constant rate
I'm trying to derive the stylised fact that the growth rate of a variable that grows at a constant rate is approximately equal to the natural log of that variable. I'm using the fact that the differential equation $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = kx(t)$$ for some constant $k$ has the unique solution $x(t) = x_0e^{kt}$ for some initial condition $x_0$. Now, the growth rate of $x(t)$ is $k$ (indeed, constant), and I'm trying to recover it by taking the natural log of $x(t)$ in the solution, but it doesn't quite work because this yields $\log(x_0) + kt$. Is there a way I could proceed from there to recover the growth rate $k$?

I mean, obviously one could recover $k$ by rearranging and thereby getting $\frac{\log\left(\frac{x(t)}{x_0}\right)}{t} = k$, but how does that relate to the growth rate being approximately equal to the natural log of the original variable?

The growth rate  is usually  defined x'(t)/x(t) so why are you sure it should be equal to the natural log of x? where did you find this statement? Otherwise how du you define "growth rate" ?

I guess you mean the derivative of the natural log

@trula I found it in Chad Jones' textbook on macroeconomics, while talking about the growth rate of GDP per capita. Yes, I'm using the standard definition of growth rate as derivative over variable.

If you use the standard definition you can easily see that x(t) is not logarithmic  just take x=alog(t) and differentiate. maybe the book really means an exponential law. Some people mix this up- So just forget about log for konstant growth rate!

Oh, I see. Well, thanks for clarifying.

As @user619894 correctly pointed out, it is the derivative of the natural log of a variable that's growing at a constant rate which is equal to its growth rate, not just the natural log. Apologies, my confusion.
Indeed, if $x(t) = x_0e^{kt}$, then $\log(x(t)) = \log(x_0) + kt$, and so $$\frac{d\log(x(t))}{dt} = k,$$ as $\log(x_0)$ is constant.
